# I would like to write "how it works" in other way

Tags: synonyms

Could you tell me the other way to say "how it works" ?

I am now making a presentation material and trying to explain how the new system works. I would like to describe it in other words because I think it may be a little casual for technical presentation. Are there any alternatives for the phrase, or can I use "how it works" for a technical presentation ?

Comment: how it functions, operates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

consider **modus operandi**  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/modus+operandi)

> A method of operating or functioning.

As in:

> This year, our [new technical system] will follow a different modus
>   operandi.

Comment: Thank you so much for your advice. I've never now such a sophisticated phrase.

Answer (score 3):

It all depends on your presentation style/contents/skills.

Here are some suggestions I've come up with:

How it functions, how it operates, how it is used, how it is put into practice, how it can be applied, how it goes.

Comment: Thank you so much for your advice. All of your recomendations are very helpful.

Comment: I'm Glad to help you.

Answer (score 2):

"System Algorithm" or "System Process Flow"

Comment: Use citations in answers, if you please.

Comment: Karthik, I'm recommending that post for deletion because it isn't really an Answer… more a hint that could be part of a Comment.

In my view either "System Algorithm" or "System Process Flow" might touch on a small part of how something worked, but Kojisugi seems to me to be asking for something much more broad, such as a"method of operation"

Comment: Thank you for all comment. All of your comments are instructive for me. I am appreciate it.